# Comparison Word Cloud - Assigning Specific Colors

Tags: r

Doing sentiment analysis and I need the comparison word cloud colors to be specific to the emotion. Code below....

```
 png("Emotion.png", width=3750,height=3500,res=250)
 comparison.cloud(tdm, scale = c(6,.5),
             random.order = FALSE,rot.per=.2,
             colors=c(trust="darkolivegreen3"
                      ,anger="firebrick4"
                      ,surprise="springgreen4"
                      ,sadness="cornflowerblue"
                      ,joy="yellow"
                      ,disgust="purple4"
                      ,fear="forestgreen"
                      ,anticipation="orangered3"),
             title.size = 1.5,max.words = 2000)
dev.off()
```

In my .png output I get the above colors but not to the assigned emotion. Is what I'm asking possible? Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do your columns match your dataset? Same order?

Comment: @BuzzLightyear yes and no, column match but not in same order

Comment: I think that's why the colors are messed up. Put them in the same order and try